# Capitalization of biological abbreviations at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations

In the beginning of a sentence, should I capitalize abbreviations such as the following:

- hPSC (human pluripotent stem cell)
- mESC (mouse embryonic stem cell)
- rDNA (recombinant deoxyribonucleic acid)

I have seen both lower and upper case for the two first, while rDNA always seems to be in lower case. I'm curious which is the linguistically correct form.

Comment: Wikipedia, at least, seems to use the lowercase letter at the beginning of a sentence, for example see the article on mRNA:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRNA

Comment: Apparently, the Chicago Manual of Style's 16th edition includes a new provision permitting sentences beginning with a brand name (e.g. iPad, iPod) which starts with a lowercase letter to retain the lowercase letter: http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/about16_rules.html.  This might be analogous.

Comment: Yeah, I use the same approach as Wikipedia on this one. I am, however, curious if there exist a correct and incorrect approach. I don't think the iPad rule applies since these are abbreviations rather than names, but it's an interesting one nonetheless.

Comment: We also see this in mathematics.  Do not begin a sentence with a variable like *x* .  Instead, re-word.  Some extra meaningless word may be used. "Now *x* is..." or "Then *x* is..." or "Note *x* is..."

Comment: This is a style issue, rather than "correctness". If you are writing for someone else (eg. a journal, then check their guidelines). If there are no such guidelines, then choose your style and **be consistent**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you encounter a situation where a "rule" (such as begin a sentence with an upper case letter) will reduce the readability of your test (*Is MESC the same as mESC?*) then rewrite.
Do not try to find a loophole or a special rule that will need to be explained or justified. The meaning of your text is paramount.

There is a reason why chemistry texts do not begin a sentence about acids and bases with pH.

Comment: I side with your advice more than my own accepted answer, _i.e._ do away with the ambiguity altogether!

Comment: Revisiting my question, I also prefer this advice as it explains the reasoning behind the rules of acheong87's answer.

Comment: @Fortiter Would you explain or give an example of what is meant by "rewrite" in this answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

According to *[Scientific Style and Format: The CBE Manual for Authors, Editors, and Publishers (C B E Style Manual)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521471540)*,

> Even if the editor chooses a style that calls for initial capitalization of every term, some terms should retain an initial lowercase letter. *[...]* 3 A standard symbol or abbreviation that begins with a lowercase letter (pH, pK', mRNA).

Also, according to [apsstylemanual.org](http://www.apsstylemanual.org/oldmanual/mechanics/capitalization.htm),

> An abbreviation that begins with a lowercase letter, or a term that must remain lowercase should not be changed to all caps when it begins a sentence; it should not be expanded. The word following should be is lowercase unless it is a proper noun or another acronym. If possible, reword the sentence so that it does not begin with the lowercase term

I don't see anything (other than the one regarding brand names) in the Chicago Manual of Style.

Answer (score 1):

Because the original post is speaking of abbreviations, I recommend following the rule to spell out the word. For example, mRNA could become "Messenger RNA..."